# C asm linux syscall in loop continue for ever

Tags: c, assembly, inline-assembly

I want to use extended asm in C language to handle a syscall (write).
everything is fine and im using

```
#define write(RESULT, FD, BUFF, SIZE)   \
    asm volatile ("syscall" :           \
        "=a" (RESULT) :                 \
        "D" (FD), "S" (BUFF), "d" (SIZE), "a" (1))
```

this works without any problem ... for example

```
#define write(RESULT, FD, BUFF, SIZE)   \
    asm volatile ("syscall" :           \
        "=a" (RESULT) :                 \
        "D" (FD), "S" (BUFF), "d" (SIZE), "a" (1))

int
main() {

    int res;
    write(res, 1, "Hello\n", 6);

    return 0;
}
```

i have no problem with this code but my problem is when i put this call

```
write(res, 1, "Hello\n", 6);
```

into a loop to use it for 100 times

```
#define write(RESULT, FD, BUFF, SIZE)   \
    asm volatile ("syscall" :           \
        "=a" (RESULT) :                 \
        "D" (FD), "S" (BUFF), "d" (SIZE), "a" (1))

int
main() {

    int res;
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        write(res, 1, "Hello\n", 6);
    }    

    return 0;
}
```

but there is a point ... i have no problem with this code too but only in debug mode .... if i set the program to (Release) or optimization mode, this loop will be executed for ever !!!!! it's like there is no 100 times limitation ... this happen only in "Release" mode which optimize my code and makes it wrong !!

yes ... the blow source code is find in "debug" but it's write "Hello" for ever (no limitation) in "Release" mode

this is the assembly code which i used [online check](https://godbolt.org/)
with -O3 option (GCC x86_64)

```
.LC0:
  .string "Hello\n"
main:
  movl $100, %ecx
  movl $.LC0, %esi
  movl $1, %edi
  movl $6, %edx
.L2:
  movl %edi, %eax
  syscall
  subl $1, %ecx
  jne .L2
  xorl %eax, %eax
  ret
```

Comment: You know you don't need inline assembler just to invoke a syscall, right?

Comment: why i don't need ?? if i use "write" fucntion, it will use the std wirte function which this syscall will happen inside it ... and also if i use (syscall) function, still there is an extra call to "syscall" function

Comment: Just include `unistd.h` and use `write` from there. No need for non-portable inline assembly.

Comment: this is the problem ... write in unistd is not a syscall ... it's a function which we "call" it and this syscall will happen inside it .... why i should call another function to use syscall inside it ??? !!

Comment: Because it's easier, more portable, and faster.

Comment: no it's not faster in execution !!! alwyse direct syscall is faster in execution and performance is better

Comment: Are you familiar with the [Linux vDSO](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/vdso.7.html)?

Comment: no but i searched a little ... still i think it has an extra function calling ...

Comment: I think you vastly overestimate how long a function call takes.

Comment: yes you right .... maybe "call" is not takes time but still it's an extra action ... and also i don't know what any extra things will happen in "write" function too !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `syscall` instruction clobbers registers `rcx` and `r11`.  The compiler assumes their values are preserved, causing an infinite loop. Add these two to the clobber list to fix the problem:

```
#define write(RESULT, FD, BUFF, SIZE)               \
    asm volatile ("syscall" :                       \
        "=a" (RESULT) :                             \
        "D" (FD), "S" (BUFF), "d" (SIZE), "a" (1) : \
        "rcx", "r11", "memory")
```

Comment: amazing !! these registers are for all syscalls? is there any other register except rax and rcx and r11?

Comment: @Jason : In Linux the only register the system call doesn't restore is RAX as it is used as a return value. So the only registers that will potentially be clobbered are RAX and the two registers the `syscall` instruction itself clobbers (RCX and R11).

Comment: Since you are passing pointers to memory through registers I'd highly recommend adding a `memory` clobber to make sure what the pointers point at are realized into memory before you do the inline assembly. Without `memory` you can generate subtle bug when optimizations are on and what is being pointed at are stack based variables. Compilers like GCC will not emit data to a buffer on the stack if it thinks the data in the buffer/array itself isn't being used.

Comment: i use "memory" only when i have pointers to pass like this const void * and ... ?

Comment: @jason If you pass the address of some data through a register like RDI or RSI (n yhis case) you are only telling the compiler that the inline assembly that the pointers are being used, not what those pointers point at.

Comment: @MichaelPetch Doesn't the `asm volatile` take care of this?  We don't write to memory, so surely a  `memory` clobber is not needed.

Comment: @jason No, `volatile` doesn't handle that. Your inline assembly code expects that the data in the buffers is written to so that by the time the `syscall` sees it that it can read the buffer so it can write the data to a file descriptor.

Comment: @MichaelPetch Can you give me an example where the compiler defers a memory write past an `asm volatile` when a pointer to that memory area is used?

Comment: @fuz : Here is an example: https://pastebin.com/D4fy0uS3   . It will do as expected when optimizations are off  since the compiler is doing all the unnecessary loads and stores to and from memory. Then try it with `-O3`. Notice that the string has been placed on the stack. If you look at the generated code you will discover the optimizer never wrote the string to the stack because it was unaware the data in the string was being used. It only knew the pointer to the string was being used as input, not what the pointer was pointing at.

Comment: wonderful example ... i think it's better to update this answer with that "memory" thing ...

Comment: You can see the effect in Godbolt when a higher optimization level is turned on. https://godbolt.org/z/TDz0iK vs when optimizations are off:

Comment: @MichaelPetch Cool example!  Thank you for this one.  LLVM seems more gracious and initialises the string anyway.

Comment: so i use "rax" and "r11" clobber for all syscalls and also use "memory" clobber for the syscalls that use a pointer to something ... true ?

Comment: @Jason Pretty much.  But do keep in mind that doing system calls directly is not really going to make your program measurably faster and you loose a lot of ways to debug or alter it (such as by using symbol interposition).  Also, the error handling is different like this; all the convenience given by the libc is lost.

Comment: @jason I think you mean "rcx" and "r11" . The output constraint `=a` already tells the compiler rax will be overwritten. You will need a `memory` clobber when you pass the pointer to something through a register. If you use a memory constraints (which don't apply here since `syscall` forces pointers in registers) like `"m"` you can avoid the use of `memory` clobber (although you may have problems even with `"m"` constraints if passing arrays of data where the length of the array isn't known to the compiler.

Comment: @jason : no problem. This kind of potential behaviour is actually documented in the GCC inline assembly documentation for the `memory` clobber. It shows some alternatives to using the `memory` clobber which include potentially adding dummy memory constraints. The docs for this can be found here: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html . Just search for `The "memory" clobber` to find the section.

Comment: @MichaelPetch: We have a canonical Q&A about the fact that pointer operands don't imply that the pointed-to memory is read or written:  [How can I indicate that the memory \*pointed\* to by an inline ASM argument may be used?](//stackoverflow.com/q/56432259)  For individual system call wrapper macros, you could of course use dummy memory inputs to avoid a `"memory"` clobber.

Comment: @fuz: LLVM isn't exactly "more gracious", it's just bad at optimizing around inline asm.  It also always picks memory for a constraint like `"rm"` that allows a memory source, even if that means spilling a var from a register first!